# Adaptive Playback in Android 4.4

Tags: android, video, https, playback, android-4.4-kitkat

I want to work on Adaptive playback the new feature in android 4.4. But I am confused how will I test the same. I will be using HTTPS links for video. Has anyone worked on it and can help how did they achieve it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the specific part of the task / setup you are unsure about?

Answer (score 1):

[CTS](http://source.android.com/compatibility/) has adaptive playback as one of its tests: [AdaptivePlaybackTest.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/AdaptivePlaybackTest.java). You should be able to reference AdaptivePlaybackTest.java for ideas on how to implement the test in your own software. Otherwise, compiling the CtsMediaTestCases package in CTS should get you a useable testing tool.