# Android Kitkat 4.4.2: Adaptive Playback impact on SurfaceFlinger

Tags: android, video, android-4.4-kitkat, stagefright, surfaceflinger

I came across this [generic question on *Adaptive Playback*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172520/adaptive-playback-in-android-4-4) in `Android` `Kitkat` in SO. However, I have some specific queries as below:

I am able to understand the implications on the `codec` and the related framework. However, there is one specific point which I am unable to understand completely.

In case of adaptive playback, the codec employs a `metadata` on it's output port which basically abstracts and packages an underlying buffer handle (in all probability a `gralloc` handle). If a resolution changes, I presume the `codec` updates the `gralloc` handle attributes directly and sends the buffer back to the `OMX` Client without a port settings change.

My first question is: Is my understanding and assumption correct?

If so, how does the `Surfaceflinger`/`SurfaceTexture` know that the incoming payload is in `metadata` format and how does it retrieve the `width` and `height` from the underlying `gralloc` implementation?

Can you please point me to the relevant sources which will help me to understand this issue better?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Every gralloc buffer has a header that specifies the dimensions and pixel format of the data.  SurfaceFlinger always receives buffers (passed by handle, via BufferQueue); "metadata mode" is a media codec concept.  Everything passes through BufferQueue  (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/kitkat-release/include/gui/BufferQueue.h and the nearby .cpp).  Heck, some key things *are* BufferQueue -- take a close look at ANativeWindow.

Comment: @fadden.. Thanks for the response. I am aware of the `BufferQueue` and it's implications. My question is specific for `VideoDecoderMetadata` being employed for `Adaptive Playback`. In this case, the `BufferQueue` doesn't get an explicit resolution change as in the current implementation i.e. there is no call for `native_window_set_buffers_geometry` when the resolution changes. In this case, I am trying to understand how `SurfaceFlinger` / `HwComposer` handles the same? Is there any explicit rule or expected to be handled by vendor? I couldn't get an exapmple of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sendFormatChange=>kWhatOutputFormatChange=>MEDIA_SET_VIDEO_SIZE=> ... =>native_window_set_buffers_dimensions

Just a clarification, lets use QC example, component recognize crop change - look for `OMX_IndexConfigCommonOutputCrop` here [omx_vdec](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/qcom/media/+/kitkat-dev/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp), then ACodec clears `mSentFormat` this makes ACodec to call `sendFormatChange` which sends `kWhatOutputFormatChange` event to NuPlayer which sends `MEDIA_SET_VIDEO_SIZE` to media player. At the second side of stick you will get `native_window_set_buffers_geometry` which forces `Surface::setBuffersDimensions`.

While OMXCodec is used `OMX_IndexConfigCommonOutputCrop` received sets `mOutputPortSettingsHaveChanged`, nearest call of `OMXCodec::read` will return `INFO_FORMAT_CHANGED` this in AwesomePlayer will make `notifyVideoSize_l` to be called and this one sends to listener `MEDIA_SET_VIDEO_SIZE`

Comment: @rg2... `sendFormatChange` is triggered when the underlying OMX component returns a port settings change. In case of `Adaptive Playback`, this is not the case as the component will not return a port settings change. Hence, my question on how `SF` would handle the same... Please correct me if I have misunderstood the same..

Comment: Nope, please check [ExecutingState::onOMXEvent](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/kitkat-dev/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp) for this purpose `OMX_IndexConfigCommonOutputCrop` is used.

Comment: @rg2.. to summarize, the component shall invoke a `portSettingsChange` with `data2` set to a change in crop dimensions. This is then picked up the `AwesomePlayer` which will set the cropping window, sets the same to native window and informs the higher layer. Is this a correct summary? If so, may I edit your response to add more details to the same and accept the same? Thanks.

Comment: I added detailed description to answer.